# Get last element from vector

Tags: rust

I have this simple piece of code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut blockchain: Vec<blockchain::Block> = Vec::new();

    let genesis_block = blockchain::create_block("genesis_block");

    blockchain::add_block_to_blockchain(&mut blockchain, genesis_block);
}
```

My error occurs here:

```
pub fn get_last_block(blockchain: &Vec<Block>) -> Block {
    return blockchain[blockchain.len() - 1];
}
```

It says:

[image]

I am pretty new to rust, so can somebody explain me why this wont work?

I just trying to get the last element of this vector.

Should i pass the ownership of this vector instead of borrowing it?

EDIT: This is my result now:

```
pub fn get_last_block(blockchain: &Vec<Block>) -> Option<&Block> {
    return blockchain.last();
}
```

`blockchain` could be empty. I check with `is_some` if its returning an value

```
let block = blockchain::get_last_block(&blockchain);
if block.is_some() {
    blockchain::print_block(block.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: I think it's trying to take ownership from inside the `Vec` because you are returning a struct. I'd suggest adding a `.clone()` to your return statement or returning a `&Block` (depending on if you want it to be read-only), or `#[derive(Copy)]` on the `Block` struct (if all of its fields are also `Copy`)

Comment: @JeremyMeadows thank you. `&Block` actually helped me. I also had to add `&` to the return `&blockchain[blockchain.len() - 1]`

Comment: @JeremyMeadows does this now mean, i receive an borrowed vector `&Vec<Block>` but the items inside are not borrowed?

Comment: To make this more idiomatic use `if let Some(block) = get_last_block(&blockchain) { `, then you don't need to `unwrap`

Comment: @Ifaruki that would return a reference to the single object, even though it does kinda look like you are borrowing the whole `Vec`. adding parentheses can highlight the order of operations where it first accesses the single element, then borrows: `&(blockchain[block.len() - 1])`, and the return type can confirm that.

Comment: [Do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), and certainly do not post _IDE errors_' text as images. Use the full compiler output from the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are borrowing the vector, you can either:

- return a reference to the block
- clone the block
- pop the block from the vec and return it (you would need to mutably borrow it instead, `&mut`)

Also, consider using an `Option` as return type, in case your vector is empty. By using this, you could directly call to [`last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last) for example, this would return a reference `&` to the last `Block`:

```rust
pub fn get_last_block(blockchain: &Vec<Block>) -> Option<&Block> {
    blockchain.last()
}
```

Nitpick, you could use a slice instead of a `Vec` in the function signature:

```rust
fn get_last_block(blockchain: &[Block])...
```

Comment: Thank you the error is gone. I am pretty new to rust so, could you explain me how Option work?

Comment: @Ifaruki, `Option` is an abstraction over values that may or may not be. Check about it in the documentaiton because it is an important part of Rust APIs.